# How to determine dependencies for all units? (Estimate refactoring cost)

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, reference, refactoring

Unfortunately I have inherited a piece of unlucky design based on a `{$IFDEF}` "hell".

What I have roughly looks like this (where `MyDbSystemB` is what I want to add)

```
unit MyTable;

interface
uses
   // ...
{$IFDEF MyDbSystemA}
   DbSystemA ,
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MyDbSystemB}
   DbSystemB ,
{$ENDIF}

type
    TMyTable = class(
        {$IFDEF MyDbSystemA}
            TSystemATable
        {$ENDIF}
        {$IFDEF MyDbSystemB}
            TSystemBTable
        {$ENDIF}
    )
    // A public interface implementation
    end;
implementation
    // ...
end.
```

A number of units reference `TMyTable`, but rely on specific functions provided with `TSystemATable`:

```
unit oldUnit;

interface
    uses MyDbTable;

type 
    TXy = class(TXyz)
    public
        procedure Foo();
    end;

implementation

procedure TXy.Foo();
var
    table : TMyTable;
begin
    table := TMyTable.Create();
    table.SomeSystemASpecificFunction;
end;
```

I'd like to find all of these references within a single reference/syntax check. But as I read here that's apparently not really possible

- [Find all compilation errors in a Delphi project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894460/find-all-compilation-errors-in-a-delphi-project).

What would be the best strategy to go for finding these files to estimate the efforts of porting?

- A plain file grep over all `*.pas` files (there may be a lot of either dead code, or just poorly decoupled stuff)?
- I'm also able to provide a *surrogate implementation* of

  ```
  TMyTable = class( { ... like above } )
      {$IFDEF MyDbSystemB}
  public
      procedure SomeSystemASpecificFunction; deprecated;
      {$ENDIF}
  end;
  ```

  with the implementation of `TMyTable`, but I'd need to estimate the refactoring cost to do that properly anyways.

  Regarding that I also could add a `deprecated` attribute along with the `SomeSystemASpecificFunction` surrogate, that will at least give me warnings.

Comment: Simply comment out the unit and see what happens. Resolve the errors you find, constantly recompiling to see what is left.

Comment: @Rudy That's exactly what I want to avoid (with that big codebase).

Comment: It is probably the only viable way to disentangle all the different references to certain classes and other identifiers.

Comment: Of course you can also use Find References...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the names of the members of `TMyTableA` that code takes a dependency on then use *Find in Files...* (or your favorite alternative `grep`-like tool) to identify references to those members in the files in your project.

This is likely to be more reliable than any compilation based check anyway.

Any tool which claims to find "all compilation errors in a project" is more often than not lying to you since there is no reliable way to discriminate between errors that have not arisen as a result of some other error earlier in the compilation.

e.g. in a C# solution it is quite common for a simple change to result in dozens if not hundreds of compilation errors which are fixed by resolving only the *first* error.

i.e. the compiler reports (e.g.) 224 errors when in fact there is only 1 error with 223 errors as a side-effect.

For the same reason, you cannot be sure that the list of errors contains all of the genuine errors you might eventually uncover.  In some cases the compiler might yet be defeated to the point of not even attempting to compile some code that contains the errors you are looking for, as a consequence of those side-effect errors.

Certainly, in the list of dozens or hundreds of errors you might then be able to `grep` to find ones that appear to be candidates for the "genuine" errors you are looking for (i.e. that reference the specific members you know to be involved in your change).  But all that does is change the data set you are searching for to locate those references.  i.e. the compilation error list rather than your project sources.

Comment: What do you think about forcing deprecation warnings?

Comment: _"which are fixed by resolving only the first error."_ It's not that simple unfortunately.

Comment: @user0042 - No, I understand that when you _know_ there are multiple errors then fixing the first one won't fix all of them.  I'm merely pointing out that a "show all errors" feature is more often less useful than it is useful, and that the use cases for those rare scenarios where it is useful can be addressed using alternative tools.  i.e. don't use the compiler as a `grep` tool.

Comment: I experienced that simple _grepping_ gets you the most significant numbers.